# Using format instead of f string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have python 3.7.4 and it has f string support. But the server I am porting my data has python < 3.6 and so does not support f string. The following code works fine in local machine:

```
directory_root = 'dataset_test/'

root_dir = listdir(directory_root)
for animal_folder in root_dir:
        animal_folder_list = listdir(f"{directory_root}/{animal_folder}")
```

But this code fails in server as it does not support f string. How could I rewrite it using format ?

Comment: I suggest reading and following the `str.format()` documentation. It never fails.

Comment: @DYZ  I have read the documentation but couldn't work it out. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
listdir("{directory_root}/{animal_folder}".format(directory_root=directory_root, animal_folder=animal_folder))
```

Or

```
listdir("{}/{}".format(directory_root, animal_folder))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use string formatting like following
`"Your string {0} {1}...{}".format(variable1, variable2, variable)`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way, that works in every environment, not only on your local linux box would be:

```
animal_folder_list = listdir(os.path.join( directory_root, animal_folder))
```

When you explicitly specify folder separator (`/`), it will break on Win-boxes or in other hostile environments. `os.path.join()` comes to the rescue =)